# For each cell in range, add cell value to array-- IF condition is met

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, foreach

It sounds like such a basic question, but I haven't been able to find any hints that could help me.

I've found stuff like `Arr = Range("A1:B10")` which would make things easy, but the issue with the above example is that it would probably shove in all the values within the specified range and that's not what I want it to do. While removing the unwanted values afterwards sounds like an option, it also sounds like a big, pointless detour that could easily be avoided.

Currently I've got the following bit:

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("Search").Range("C7:C15").Cells
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then fcat() = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
Next cell
```

I took a guess earlier and tried `fcat(cell)` as well, but so far I've only been getting type mismatch errors on `fcat() = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value` and I'm not entirely sure what all else to try.

Thank you for your time, and let me know if there's anything else I can do to improve my question.

Comment: you have to  use indexnumbers to address the locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the [ReDim statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) on the array variable.

```
Sub fcat()
    Dim fcat As Variant, cell As Range

    ReDim fcat(0)
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Search").Range("C7:C15").Cells
        If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
            fcat(UBound(fcat)) = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            ReDim Preserve fcat(UBound(fcat) + 1)
        End If
    Next cell
    ReDim Preserve fcat(UBound(fcat) - 1)

    'try it out
    Dim v As Long
    Debug.Print LBound(fcat) & ":" & UBound(fcat)
    For v = LBound(fcat) To UBound(fcat)
        Debug.Print fcat(v)
    Next v
End Sub
```

[image: REDIM statement]

Results from the Immediate window:

```
fcat
0:6
 13 
 32 
 6 
 20 
 7
```

The variable does not automatically grow or shirink in size. Its lower and upper boundaries are indicated by the [LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx). You can assign a size to the array and fill it or change the size with Redim using the Preserve option to maintain the data it already contains.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem.

```
Dim i as integer

i = 0
For Each cell In Worksheets("Search").Range("C7:C15").Cells
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then 
      fcat(i) = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
      i = i +1
    end if
Next cell
```

Comment: And this is where I kick myself for not having thought of such a simple solution myself. Thank you for your quick response! Although now I'm getting an error saying 'subscript out of range', so I guess I'll be looking into that next.

Comment: do also check the answer of @jepeed

Answer (score 0):

What about using standard functions in excel?
Like sumif

You use the SUMIF function to sum the values in a range that meet criteria that you specify. For example, suppose that in a column that contains numbers, you want to sum only the values that are larger than 5. You can use the following formula:

=SUMIF(B2:B25,">5")

In this example, the criteria is applied to the values that are being summed. If you want, you can apply the criteria to one range and sum the corresponding values in a different range. For example, the formula =SUMIF(B2:B5, "John", C2:C5) sums only the values in the range C2:C5, where the corresponding cells in the range B2:B5 equal "John."